# Should we unfreeze Politics chat?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

The main Politics chat room, Agora, has been programmatically frozen for inactivity. Should it be unfrozen?

Comment: Let the deafening silence on the subject (and in the chatroom) be your guide....

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify under which circumstances a room is [frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/frozen-rooms/info). A room is frozen after 14 days without any activity. (A room can be deleted already after 7 days if there is almost no activity in there, but this is not the case for the type of room you are asking about - basically the "main"<sup>1</sup> chatroom for the site.)

The system always keeps at least one room associated with the site alive - not counting the rooms which were creating by moving comments to chat.<sup>2</sup> Specifically, in the case of this site, at the moment there are two "standard" rooms with [Politics as a parents site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=politics.stackexchange.com). One of them is [Política Brasil](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/74751/politica-brasil) which seems to be rather active. The room named [Agora](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6619/agora) seems to be relatively silent. (So it is not that surprising that if has been [frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=6619&q=frozen&user=-2) and [unfrozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=6619&q=unfrozen&user=-2) in the past.)

One solution to prevent the room from getting frozen would be to start using it a bit more - it's possible that eventually there will be a community of users who visit the room regularly and discuss various thing, related specifically to this site or to politics in general.

I am not sure to which extent a solution like this would be ideal, but I'll mention that some sites use a bot to prevent freezing of a specific room - this bot posts a message into the room after several days of silence.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Strictly speaking, there is not such a thing as "the main chatroom" in Stack Exchange terminology. But usually when a site is created, also a separate room is created together with some [welcome message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2012/12/4) posted at the beginning. The term *main chatroom* often refers to the room like this. On some sites, the users actually started to use a different room from the room which was created in this way - the term *main chatroom* is sometimes used also in this sense, i.e., the room which is commonly used for general discussions related to the specific site.

<sup>2</sup>Details about this can be found in [various posts on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frozen-rooms). But the information related to this seems to be scattered in several posts - at least I did not find a single post which gives a concise summary.

<sup>3</sup>Possibly there are also some other bots that can be used for this. The one I am aware of is [Generic Bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/382851/generic-bot?tab=recent). Creator of this room is the user Floern, you can find them quite often in [the SOBotics room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/111347/sobotics). So if this way of prevention freezing sounds like a good idea, you might try to contact them and ask them whether they could add also this room to the list.