# The many memes of Politics and its chats

Tags: discussion

> In the style of [The many memes of meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

Catchphrases and concepts that spread from person to person are known as [memes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme_(Internet)), which, courtesy the internet, can now explode across the earth like a highly contagious virus (hence "going viral"). As with their IRL counterparts, some infectious diseases are global, while others are endemic to specific regions.

Here we will try and list some of these memes that are relevant to politics SE. one meme per answer please.

Comment: Note to close voter(s): the same post exists on meta, as well as multiple other per-site metas across the network. If you think that this post is off topic, bring it up with all of these posts [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

Comment: My first thought on seeing this was "Wait, do we actually _have_ any used chat rooms? Or memes?"

Comment: @Bobson we have [Agora](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6619/agora)

Answer (score 4):

**Meme**: *This room has been automatically frozen for inactivity*.

**Originator**: [Feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds).

**Cultural Height**: When the room falls silent.

**Background**: Feeds is one of our more active chat users. Besides posting some feed items, its main objective is to freeze our chat room.

**Related**: [Should we unfreeze Politics chat?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3856)